# Unexpected idenifier errors in xCode on cocos 2d game

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import "MainScene.h"

static const CGFloat scrollSpeed = 80.f;

@implementation MainScene {
     CCSprite *_hero;
     CCPhysicsNode *_physicsNode;
     CCNode *_ground1;
     CCNode *_ground2;
     NSArray *_grounds;
     NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;
}

- (void)didLoadFromCCB {
    _grounds = @[_ground1, _ground2];
    self.userInteractionEnabled =TRUE;
}

- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];

}
   // _sinceTouch+=delta;
    _hero.rotation = clampf(_hero.rotation, -30.f, 90.f);
    if (_hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation) {
        float angularVelocity = clampf(_hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity, -2.f, 1.f);
        _hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
    }



//position of hero
    - (void)update: (CCTime) delta {

    _hero.position = ccp(_hero.position.x + delta * scrollSpeed, _hero.position.y);
    _physicsNode.position = ccp(_physicsNode.position.x - (scrollSpeed *delta), _physicsNode.position.y);
// loop the ground
    for (CCNode *ground in _grounds) {

        // get the world position of the ground
        CGPoint groundWorldPosition = [_physicsNode convertToWorldSpace:ground.position];

        // get the screen position of the ground
        CGPoint groundScreenPosition = [self convertToNodeSpace:groundWorldPosition];

        // if the left corner is one complete width off the screen, move it to the right
        if (groundScreenPosition.x <= (-1 * ground.contentSize.width)) {
            ground.position = ccp(ground.position.x + 2 * ground.contentSize.width, ground.position.y);
            // clamp velocity
            float yVelocity = clampf(_hero.physicsBody.velocity.y, -1 * MAXFLOAT, 200.f);
            _hero.physicsBody.velocity = ccp(0, yVelocity);

            NSTimeInterval _sinceTouch;
            if ((_sinceTouch > 0.5f)) {
                [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:-40000.f*delta];
            }

        }
        - (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
            [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];
            [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:10000.f];
            _sinceTouch = 0.f;
        }
    }
}



@end
```

![errors][1]

Hello internet,

I am a highschool student and for my senior project I am making a flappy bird clone,  This is due in a couple weeks and I need some help with some errors in the code, the first being a unexpected type name for _hero in this line `// _sinceTouch+=delta;
    _hero.rotation = clampf(_hero.rotation, -30.f, 90.f);` and an unexpected identifier or "("  on the following line.

There is also a `- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {` a undeclared use of idenifier "touchbegan" on this line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEZCc.png

Comment: The code giving you the unexpected type name error is outside of any method. Code must be inside a method, not between methods.

Comment: can you elaborate on that a little more, sorry imma n00b:)

Comment: You're a n00b and you "wrote" the code above, eh?

Comment: i did it with a lot of help for tutorials

Answer (score 0):

```
// _sinceTouch+=delta;

_hero.rotation = clampf(_hero.rotation, -30.f, 90.f);
if (_hero.physicsBody.allowsRotation) {
    float angularVelocity = clampf(_hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity, -2.f, 1.f);
    _hero.physicsBody.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
}
```

Is not in a lexical scope. There is no function around it. Remove that code or put it in a relevant area.

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   [_hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 400.f)];
   [_hero.physicsBody applyAngularImpulse:10000.f];
   _sinceTouch = 0.f;
}
```

Is scoped inside another function, which is forbidden. Move this to right before

```
@end
```

and that error will go away.